# wkhtmltopdf text split across 2 pages

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using wkhtmltopdf (through the 'pdfkit' ruby gem) to generate pdf from html. There is a section in the page where the text content is lengthy, and it usually spans 2 (or more) pages. What happens sometimes is that a line of text is split across pages. Here's an image to help you understand what I mean:

[image]

Now I have done my fair bit of research on this: for example I have tried CSS fix on the sorrounding div (which was suggested in some other stackoverflow questions), like so:

```
page-break-inside:avoid !important;
```

and/or

```
page-break-before: always !important;
```

didn't work.

I have also tried:

```
display: block !important;
```

which didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

FYI: I am using the latest version of wkhtmltopdf: wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1

Comment: Could you show/link to the HTML and the CSS? I use wkhtmltopdf daily and for me this is not an issue so I'd like to test with your data and scenario.

Comment: hmm.. I passed the same html content to wkhtmltopdf's "linux" static binary, and the issue disappeared. I am now thinking this might be an issue with the Mac version. I'll post the solution once I find it out. In the meantime, I will appreciate any help. p.s. Seems like when you do wkhtmltopdf --version on homebrew-installed package, it displays the wrong version number. The actual installed version seems to be 0.10 rc.

Comment: Check if this or parent divs have overflow set as hidden. If so, change it to visible. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is on for `wicked-pdf` and`wkhtmltopdf`.

Once got into similar kind of issue but fixed by changing the contents in `configuration` folder `wicked_pdf.rb` file to

```
WickedPdf.config = {
    :layout => "pdf.html",
    :margin => {    :top=> 60, #previously 40
                    :bottom => 40, #previously 20
                    :left=> 30,
                    :right => 30},
    :header => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_header.html'}},
    :footer => {:html => { :template=> 'layouts/pdf_footer.html'}},
    :exe_path => '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

changing from `previous to new values`, it worked fine on local machine.

Whenever you make changes in `wicked_pdf.rb` the server must be re-started, and make sure `page-break-before: always` is at right place.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i am using pdfkit. and i have used page-break-before: always; on several container/parent divs, without any success. this seems to be a wkhtmltopdf issue, rather than that of a library.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was resolved by commenting out the following css:

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

As [El Kopyto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354499/el-kopyto) stated in one of the comments to a previous answer:

> Check if this or parent divs have overflow set as hidden. If so, change it to visible.

In my case, removing the overflow property altogether did the job.